# How to : customize AOSP settings?

Tags: android, localization, android-source

Im trying to build aosp for my devkit, and i'd like to know where
should i look to for :

1. - to changing font size of texts
     in settings section ( i've replaced
     droid fonts with another one but the
     new font kind large) or global font
     setting.
2. - to change position of texts in
     settings section ( usually all texts
     are
     in left side, i want to try and put it in right side for example).
3. - the language locale names  that
     showed in settings/language &
     keyboards.. where are they stored .
     i looked into `LocalePicker.java` but
     could not figure it out.

For example i want to change a locale name from english to it's native
language (In some android builds i've seen arabic locale was in english, and
some other builds it was shown in native arabic العربية).